# trying to understand event handler codes in js

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="example.css">
<div class="d1">1  
    <div class="d2">2
        <div class="d3">3 
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
<script>
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div')
for(var i=0; i<divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].onclick = function(e) {
    e = e || event
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement
    this.style.backgroundColor='yellow'    
    alert("target = "+target.className+", this="+this.className)
    this.style.backgroundColor = ''
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Above code is from http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

Questions:

1. `divs[i].onclick`, `divs` is htmlcollection, it is not an arrary, how could we use array style:`array[i]`? for event handler, why we do not put `var` in front of it(such as `var divs[i].onclick`)?
2. `e = e || event`, why put `event` here? and why not put `var` in front of `e`, is that because `e` is the global variable?

Comment: for e = e || event its for compatibility reasons in IE the event object is there with out passing it to the Event handler but in others the event must be passed through the argument of the event handler

Comment: **e** is a params of **function(e)**, if you are not put it, `e = e || event` return event(default event var of function)

Comment: It seems JS likes array syntax: new String("HELLO")[0] is the same as new String("HELLO").charAt(0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `divs[i].onclick`, `divs` is htmlcollection, it is not an arrary, how could we use array style?

It's actually a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), which is an "array-like" object, in that it has a `length` property and the properties you actually care about are numerically keyed.

> for event handler, why we do not put `var` in front of it?

Because you are *referencing* an element of the `NodeList`. You do not want to declare a new variable, you want to use an existing reference.

> `e = e || event`, why put event here?

This is to handle old versions of Internet Explorer, where event objects were not passed to handlers but were instead accessible as `window.event`.

> why not put var in front of `e`, is that because `e` is the global variable?

No, it's passed into the event handler function as an argument so there's no need to declare it inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

> divs[i].onclick, divs is htmlcollection, it is not an arrary, how could we use array style:array[i]?

"HTML collections" (NodeLists) are *specified* to allow index-based access.

> for event handler, why we do not put var in front of it(such as var divs[i].onclick)?

Because that would make no sense at all. You are assigning a value to an attribute of an existing object - no variables involved, nor any sense in trying to use `var` keyword here.

> e = e || event, why put event here? and why not put var in front of e, is that because e is the global variable?

That's a hack for (older) IE that otherwise do not pass the event object to the handler function correctly. And the variable e is local already because it was defined as parameter of the function.

Answer (score 0):

`var divs` is used by `document.getElementByTagName`, so it is already defined.
`var e` is also defined in `function(e)` so you don't need to define it.

Answer (score 0):

Q1:

`divs` is an array which contains HTMLElement objects. So `divs[i]` is a HTMLElement on which you can define an onclick event. It is a shortcut for

```
var element = divs[i];
element.onclick = function(e){
...
```

Q2:

`e` is a argument of the listener event function. Different browsers invoke the event function differently. In some browsers `event` object is available explicitly inside the function and some browsers pass the event object as argument `e`. So to make the code browser independent we use this snippet `e = e || event`. In case the `e` argument is non-null, the code will use that object, otherwise when `e` is null `event` object should be available. It is not possible that both will be null.